# How to update the RecyclerView Adapter when I add new item in the DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, backendless

I have RecyclerView adapter which loads items when the fragment is initialized. Also I have DialogFragment to add new item. So, How do I know, if the new item is added in the DialogFragment and update the adapter?

I tried to use RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver, but then I realized that DialogFragment does not know anything about Adapter in the fragment.

Comment: define a method inside your recyclerview adapter which will insert new data passed from DialogFragment & after adding the new data to your Collection which might be a list , call notifyDataSetChanged() to reflect the changes in recyclerview.